# Collection types: How to store a list of bool,string?

Tags: c++

I'm new to datatypes and I want to store a list of messages. The messages can either be positive or negative. I want the GUI to be able to display those messages from old to new. I need to be able to differentiate between displaying the full collection of messages and only the positive or negative ones.

The size of the collection will be in the 10'000 and there will be duplicate messages/keys.

Which container should I use to achieve this and how would I go on with displaying only the positive messages / all the messages?

Comment: Why not create a message class that contains the fields you need (string, bool, whatever else you may need to add later)?  Then you can store instances of that class in a list.

Comment: You mention "keys" - do you need to be able to look up the messages via these keys?

Comment: @sfjac yes as I said I want to store the strings with a bool. And then either read only the true (or false) ones from the collection or both (the complet list from old to new).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you store some information and a single "tag" (say, a `std::string` and a `bool`) one approach is to store `std::pair<bool,string>` in a collection with fixed iteration order, such as `std::vector<T>` or `std::list<T>`:

```
std::vector<std::pair<bool,std::string> > messages;
```

To print all positive messages, you could iterate the pairs, and pick ones with the positive/negative flag set to a specific value:

```
for (std::pair<bool,std::string> & p : messages ) {
    if (p.first) { // Print only positive messages
        cout << p.second << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: how do I add something to this vector? is messages.insert(true,"positive message") wrong?

Comment: @isADon You need to call `make_pair`, like this: `messages.push_back(make_pair<bool,string>(true, "positive message"))`